# how to make a live555 server do streaming by using a rtsp address instead a file

Tags: c++, rtsp, live555

I have been studying testOnDemandRTSPServer code and I want to do streaming by taking input from a live source by using a rtsp address. 
I have read that I have to modify OnDemandServerMediaSubsession and createNewStreamSource() and createNewRTPSink() functions. 
I don't know how to do this. I don't know how to start with this. I have been searching information via Internet but I haven't found anything. Please some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you need is their [proxyServer](http://www.live555.com/proxyServer/). It would act like a client for your RTSP source and as a server for other clients.

The common case is a source that knows how to perform a unicast stream and required to do multicast. (Usually IP cameras)